# Why on the click of "choose image" button, after choosing a image application crashes?

Tags: android

I have a Parent class MainActivity which calls this on the click of button and after that when I click on Choose image button, there starts a new intent which allows me to select a particular image from Gallery but if I do the same my application crashes. Also, I have override the onActivityResult Method.

check..

### Add.java

```
package com.apna.mycontacts;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public  class Add extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{
EditText fname,lname;
Button save,pic;
String picturepath,str;
ImageView iv;
private static final int SELECTED_PICTURE = 1;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        pic=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        fname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    lname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    pic.setOnClickListener(this);

}
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
    case SELECTED_PICTURE:

        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
        Uri selectedimage=data.getData();
        String[] filename={ MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(selectedimage, filename, null,null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(filename[0]);
         picturepath= cursor.getString(columnIndex);
         cursor.close();

Bitmap yourselectedimage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturepath);
        Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(yourselectedimage);
        iv.setBackground(d);
        Log.e("abc","error ");
        }
    }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button1:
        Intent i=new Intent();
        i.putExtra("fname",fname.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("lname",lname.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("image",picturepath);
        setResult(5,i);
        finish();   
        break;
        case R.id.button2:
                    Intent l=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(l,SELECTED_PICTURE);         
                    break;

        }
    }
}
```

and

onActivityResult....

---

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==5)
    {
        String a=data.getStringExtra("fname");
        String b=data.getStringExtra("lname");
        String c=data.getStringExtra("image");
        tv.setText(c);
        first.add(a);
        last.add(b);
        cd.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    }
```

please help me..

Comment: you should provide crash log

Comment: You should also post the stack trace of your crash.

Comment: Please provide crash log and highlight the statement causing crash in your question.

Comment: check this image....>>>>http://postimg.org/image/j0259z2ld/c27548d0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error seems to be telling you that `iv` is not defined when you call `iv.setBackground(d)`. That is because you are calling `findViewById` with a drawable instead of an id. Probably you have some element in your layout that you mean to set the background of. You need to be using that element's id.

Comment: hey! can u tell me how to give paths of images in the form of List such that they can be fetched from their paths..??